# How could I create combinations of removed dashes in SQL Server string?

Tags: sql-server

I've been looking for a table-valued function for SQL Server that can do the following:

Input string:  `A-B-C-D` (or any length string with dash-separated characters, like `XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA-777-888`)

Output strings (all combinations of removed dashes):

```
ABCD, A-BCD, AB-CD, ABC-D, A-B-CD, AB-C-D, A-B-C-D
```

I've noticed the pattern follows a binary counter with respect to which dash should be removed to generate the combinations.  In the example above, you could remove the dashes associated with the 0 positions of 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, and 111. However I don't see how to do this in SQL Server. Have any of you tackled this challenge before? Thank you!

Comment: What a strange requirement. What is the actual usage for something like this? I notice that the order of the "values" stays consistent.

Comment: Sean, I'm searching unstructured text for a match.  My DB would have A-B-C, and then the unstructured text would might show "Here is item A-BC."  Unfortunately I can't just remove all dashes because it would create too many false matches.

Comment: Use full text search

Comment: Generating all combinations of dashes and searching for them is virtually guaranteed to perform even worse, than just removing the dashes and dealing with the false hits, as it's performance is always going to be exponential *or worse*.

Answer (score 1):

For this first section, I'm going to split the string into table / columns using XML.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE
( ID INT,
  NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
 )

 INSERT INTO @Test 
 VALUES( 1, 'XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA-777-888' )

 DECLARE @ColSplit TABLE
 (
    Id int,
    Col1 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col2 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col3 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col4 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col5 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col6 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col7 VARCHAR(MAX),
    Col8 VARCHAR(MAX)
 )

;WITH FormSplitXML
AS
(
    Select Id, Name,
    CONVERT(XML,'<r><n>' + REPLACE(Name, '-', '</n><n>') + '</n></r>') AS X
    FROM @Test
)

INSERT INTO @ColSplit
SELECT  Id,  
    i.value('n[1]','varchar(100)') AS Col1,
    i.value('n[2]','varchar(100)') AS Col2,
    i.value('n[3]','varchar(100)') AS Col3,
    i.value('n[4]','varchar(100)') AS Col4,
    i.value('n[5]','varchar(100)') AS Col5,
    i.value('n[6]','varchar(100)') AS Col6,
    i.value('n[7]','varchar(100)') AS Col7,
    i.value('n[8]','varchar(100)') AS Col8
FROM FormSplitXML Spt 
CROSS APPLY Spt.X.nodes('/r') x(i)
```

This forms a table with this output:

```
SELECT * FROM @ColSplit

Id  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8
1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL
```

Next I am going to make a bit array table of all of the possible bit combinations:

```
DECLARE @BitTable TABLE
(
    v int,
    V1 BIT,
    V2 BIT,
    V3 BIT,
    V4 BIT,
    V5 BIT,
    V6 BIT,
    V7 BIT,
    V8 BIT
)

Declare @t table (v integer not null primary key, check(v >= 0));

;WITH
a AS (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 1),
b AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM a AS x, a AS y),
c AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM b AS x, b AS y),
d AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM c AS x, c AS y),
e AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM d AS x, d AS y),
f AS (SELECT 1 AS i FROM e AS x, e AS y),
numbers AS 
(
    SELECT TOP(255)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS number
    FROM f
)


Insert into @t 
SELECT number FROM numbers


INSERT INTO @BitTable
( v, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6, V7, V8 )
SELECT
    v,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 1) AS V1,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 2) AS V2,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 4) AS V3,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 8) AS V4,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 16) AS V5,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 32) AS V6,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 64) AS V7,
    CONVERT(BIT, v & 128) AS V8
FROM
@t
```

Here is the output of the bittable (only the first 10 rows, it keeps going to 255)

```
SELECT * FROM @BitTable
v   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
7   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
9   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Now using the bit table and the split columns, I am going to put a string together of all of the possible combinations:

```
SELECT
    bt.*,
    t.*,
    CASE WHEN bt.V1 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col1,'') + '-' ELSE t.Col1 END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V2 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col2,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col2,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V3 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col3,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col3,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V4 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col4,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col4,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V5 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col5,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col5,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V6 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col6,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col6,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V7 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col7,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col7,'') END +
    CASE WHEN bt.V8 = 1 THEN ISNULL(t.Col8,'') + '-' ELSE ISNULL(t.Col8,'') END
FROM @BitTable bt
CROSS JOIN @ColSplit t
```

Here is the output (snipped to 10 rows, it goes to 255):

```
v   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  Id  Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    (No column name)
1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XX-W2ZZZAAA777888
2   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XXW2-ZZZAAA777888
3   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XX-W2-ZZZAAA777888
4   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XXW2ZZZ-AAA777888
5   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XX-W2ZZZ-AAA777888
6   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XXW2-ZZZ-AAA777888
7   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA777888
8   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XXW2ZZZAAA-777888
9   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XX-W2ZZZAAA-777888
10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   XX  W2  ZZZ AAA 777 888 NULL    NULL    XXW2-ZZZAAA-777888
```

Here you go, hope it helps.

Comment: Some caveats, the tables are set for 8 cols / bits, if you want more columns split, you would have to increase it.  From your sample data you only had 6, so I padded it to 8 to give you a little room.

Comment: Kevin, thank you this is helpful.  After considering your solution, I found a way to shrink the code as shown below.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to find something that did not involve multiple loops and would be more set-based. A `CROSS JOIN` is good for combinations as that is what a Cross Join / Cartesian-product is. But I still had to resort to Dynamic SQL due to the variable nature of how many dashes there might be. "But you can't do Dynamic SQL in a function!" I keep hearing that, yet I am not entirely convinced due to the following SQLCLR TVF. It constructs a query that, for the example input of `A-B-C-D`, looks like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(tab1.part, tab2.part, tab3.part, tab4.part) AS [Combinations]
FROM (SELECT N'A') tab1(part)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT N'B' UNION ALL SELECT N'-B') tab2(part)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT N'C' UNION ALL SELECT N'-C') tab3(part)
CROSS JOIN (SELECT N'D' UNION ALL SELECT N'-D') tab4(part)
```

This dynamic construction makes use of the pattern of combinations being:

> FirstElement + {Cartesian Product of no-dash and preceding-dash versions of remaining elements}

The .Net / C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public class TVF
{
    public static void ReturnCombo(object Combination, out SqlString Combo)
    {
        Combo = (string)Combination;
    }

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(FillRowMethodName = "ReturnCombo",
          TableDefinition = "Combo NVARCHAR(500)", DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static IEnumerable GetCombinations([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlString DashedThingy)
    {
        List<string> _Combinations = new List<string>();
        int _PartNum = 0;
        StringBuilder _FirstPart = new StringBuilder("SELECT CONCAT(tab1.part");
        StringBuilder _SecondPart = new StringBuilder(") AS [Combinations]\n");

        foreach (string _Part in DashedThingy.Value.Split(new char[1] { '-' }))
        {
            _PartNum++;

            if (_PartNum == 1)
            {
                _SecondPart.Append("FROM (SELECT N'").Append(_Part).AppendLine("') tab1(part)");
            }
            else
            {
                _FirstPart.Append(", tab").Append(_PartNum).Append(".part");
                _SecondPart.Append("CROSS JOIN (SELECT N'").Append(_Part);
                _SecondPart.Append("' UNION ALL SELECT N'-").Append(_Part);
                _SecondPart.Append("') tab").Append(_PartNum).AppendLine("(part)");
            }
        }

        SqlConnection _Connection = new SqlConnection("Context Connection = true;");
        SqlCommand _Command = new SqlCommand();
        _Command.Connection = _Connection;
        _Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        _Command.CommandText = _FirstPart.ToString() + _SecondPart.ToString();
        SqlDataReader _Reader = null;

        try
        {
            _Connection.Open();
            _Reader = _Command.ExecuteReader();

            while (_Reader.Read())
            {
                _Combinations.Add(_Reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (_Reader != null && !_Reader.IsClosed)
            {
                _Reader.Close();
            }
            if (_Connection != null && _Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                _Connection.Close();
            }
        }

        return _Combinations;
    }
}
```

And the SQL to create it is:

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY [GetCombinations]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 'C:\path\to\DLL'
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCombinations]
(@DashedThingy NVARCHAR (MAX))
RETURNS TABLE ([Combo] NVARCHAR (500) NULL)
AS EXTERNAL NAME [GetCombinations].[TVF].[GetCombinations];
```

This is fully dynamic so it can handle any number of dashes. It finds the missing combination that is not in the example output (A-BC-D) and handles the other example easily:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetCombinations('XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA-777-888');
```

Returns:

> Combo
>   ---------
>   XXW2ZZZAAA777888
>   XXW2-ZZZAAA777888
>   XXW2ZZZ-AAA777888
>   XXW2-ZZZ-AAA777888
>   XXW2ZZZAAA-777888
>   XXW2-ZZZAAA-777888
>   XXW2ZZZ-AAA-777888
>   XXW2-ZZZ-AAA-777888
>   XX-W2ZZZAAA777888
>   XX-W2-ZZZAAA777888
>   XX-W2ZZZ-AAA777888
>   XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA777888
>   XX-W2ZZZAAA-777888
>   XX-W2-ZZZAAA-777888
>   XX-W2ZZZ-AAA-777888
>   XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA-777888
>   XXW2ZZZAAA777-888
>   XXW2-ZZZAAA777-888
>   XXW2ZZZ-AAA777-888
>   XXW2-ZZZ-AAA777-888
>   XXW2ZZZAAA-777-888
>   XXW2-ZZZAAA-777-888
>   XXW2ZZZ-AAA-777-888
>   XXW2-ZZZ-AAA-777-888
>   XX-W2ZZZAAA777-888
>   XX-W2-ZZZAAA777-888
>   XX-W2ZZZ-AAA777-888
>   XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA777-888
>   XX-W2ZZZAAA-777-888
>   XX-W2-ZZZAAA-777-888
>   XX-W2ZZZ-AAA-777-888
>   XX-W2-ZZZ-AAA-777-888

Comment: Thank you srutzky.  This looks like a viable solution too.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I found to work inside MSSQL and accept any count of dashes.  Main table-value function:

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Outputs all possible combinations of dash and no dash in a string
-- Test:  Select * From dbo.[fnDashCombinations]('A')
-- Test:  Select * From dbo.[fnDashCombinations]('A-B')
-- Test:  Select * From dbo.[fnDashCombinations]('AB-CD-EF-11-22')
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDashCombinations] 
(   
    @InputText VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS @output TABLE(ModelName VARCHAR(50)) 
BEGIN 
    --Get the count of dashes
    DECLARE @DashCount INT
    SET @DashCount = (select len(@InputText) - len(replace(@InputText, '-', '')))

    --Count through the dashes 
    DECLARE @OuterIterator INT
    DECLARE @InnerIterator INT
    DECLARE @OuterIteratorLimit INT
    DECLARE @DashesAsBinary VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @DashLocation INT
    DECLARE @TextTemp VARCHAR(50)

    SET @OuterIteratorLimit = POWER(2, @DashCount) - 1

    SET @OuterIterator = 0
    WHILE @OuterIterator < @OuterIteratorLimit
    BEGIN
        --Convert  the dash count into the equivalent binary string
        SET @TextTemp = @InputText
        SET @DashesAsBinary = dbo.fnBinaryString(@OuterIterator, @DashCount)
        SET @DashLocation = 0
        SET @InnerIterator = 0

        --Loop thru @DashesAsBinary and remove the dash if there's a zero 
        WHILE @InnerIterator < @DashCount
        BEGIN
            SET @DashLocation = CHARINDEX('-', @TextTemp, @DashLocation + 1)
            IF SUBSTRING(@DashesAsBinary, @InnerIterator + 1, 1) = '0'
            BEGIN   --Replace with underscore for now to keep string length constant            
                SET @TextTemp = dbo.fnReplaceCharAtPos(@TextTemp, @DashLocation, '_')
            END

            SET @InnerIterator = @InnerIterator + 1
        END

        INSERT INTO @output SELECT REPLACE(@TextTemp, '_', '') --Finally remove extra chars
        SET @OuterIterator = @OuterIterator + 1
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Additional scalar function that is called to convert the iterator into a binary string, like 3 = '011' (found most of this code elsewhere):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBinaryString] (@IncomingNumber int, @MinChars int)
RETURNS varchar(200)
as
BEGIN

    DECLARE @BinNumber  VARCHAR(200)
    SET @BinNumber = ''

    WHILE @IncomingNumber <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @BinNumber = SUBSTRING('0123456789', (@IncomingNumber % 2) + 1, 1) + @BinNumber
        SET @IncomingNumber = @IncomingNumber / 2
    END

    if (LEN(@BinNumber) < @MinChars)
        SET @BinNumber = REPLICATE('0', @MinChars - LEN(@BinNumber)) + @BinNumber

    RETURN @BinNumber

END
```

Additional scalar function that is called to replace a character at a position, used in this case to replace a dash with an underscore (found this code elsewhere):

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnReplaceCharAtPos](@Str varchar(8000),@Pos int, @Chr char(1))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS  
BEGIN 
    declare @Res varchar(8000)
    set @Res=left(@Str,@Pos-1) + @Chr  + right(@Str,len(@Str)-@Pos)
    return @Res
END
```